# Display text from ID in other ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display text from one ID in another, but it only works once. So I load the page, hover over the title with the ID and then another and it just stays on the first one.

HTML

```
<div class="cp_widget_content" id="portfolio_content_area">

<b class="cp_widget_title" id="portfolio_title_area">'.get_the_title().'</b>';

<div id="title_hover">Test</div>
```

jQuery

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        (function ($) 
        { 
            $('#portfolio_title_area').hover(function()
            {
                $('#title_hover').text($('#portfolio_title_area').text());
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you hover over one id you are trying to view another id and hide others?

Comment: When I hover over the first ID, the output text just stays the same even when I hover over other ID's.

Comment: Just a note on the side, `jQuery(function ($) {/* code here*/});` could replace all the boilerplate code you wrap your jQuery object with.

Comment: are you using `id` duplicately??

Comment: You have used jQuery instead of javascript. For the Js version, you can check my post below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, your comments indicate that you have multiple titles, which should be displayed in `#title_hover` when hovering. If so, don't use ids, use a class selector, e.g.:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  // keep a reference to the target, so we
  // don't need to query on every enter/leave
  const $title = $('#title_hover');
  
  // store original text
  const fallback = $title.text();

  $('.cp_widget_title').on({
    // on enter
    'mouseenter': function() {
      // overwrite with text from hovered element
      $title.text($(this).text());
    },
    // on leave
    'mouseleave': function() {
      // reset to previous text
      $title.text(fallback);
    },
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b class="cp_widget_title">Some title 1</b>
<b class="cp_widget_title">Some title 2</b>
<b class="cp_widget_title">Some title 3</b>
<b class="cp_widget_title">Some title 4</b>
<div id="title_hover">Test</div>
```

---

On a side note, regarding the boilerplate to get a reference to `jQuery` as `$` in `noConflict`-mode, instead of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    (function ($) { 
        // code
    })(jQuery);
});
```

you can use the following, which is equivalent:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        (function ($) 
        { 
            $('#portfolio_title_area').hover(function()
            {
                $('#title_hover').text($('#portfolio_title_area').text());
            }, function() {
                $('#title_hover').text('');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you once change it and never ask it to change back when you're done hovering:

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        (function ($) 
        { 
          var text = $('#title_hover').text();
            $('#portfolio_title_area').mouseover(function()
            {
                $('#title_hover').text($('#portfolio_title_area').text());
            });
            $('#portfolio_title_area').mouseout(function()
            {
                $('#title_hover').text(text);
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cp_widget_content" id="portfolio_content_area">

<b class="cp_widget_title" id="portfolio_title_area">'.get_the_title().'</b>';

<div id="title_hover">Test</div>
```

Use `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead of `hover`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `mouseleave`  function

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    (function ($) 
    { 
        $('#portfolio_title_area').hover(function()
        {
            $('#title_hover').text($('#portfolio_title_area').text());
        });
            $('#portfolio_title_area').mouseleave(function()
        {
            $('#title_hover').text('Test');
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function disp(idname)
{
 var x=document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("title_hover").innerHTML=x;
}
function def()
{
 document.getElementById("title_hover").innerHTML="Test";
}
```

```html
<div class="cp_widget_content" id="portfolio_content_area">
</div>
<b class="cp_widget_title" id="portfolio_title_area" onmouseover="disp(this.id)" onmouseout="def()">'.get_the_title().'</b>';
<br><br><br><hr>
<div id="title_hover">Test</div>
<hr>
```

JScript version...

Answer (score -1):

You are using IIFE (i.e Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

```
((function ($) 
{ 

})(jQuery);
```

This is executed only once and that too even before document.ready is executed. So it is working only once.

You can even do it without IIFE.

Comment: This is not correct, as the IIFE is in a `jQuery(document).ready(function {});` block, so it's executed at the *right* time. And it being executed only once is irrelevant as it's only purpose is to get a handle to `jQuery` as `$`.

Comment: However still it makes no sense even to put an IIFE inside document.ready. Whenever it is required to initialize any part of code before document.ready or body onload, the best way is IIFE. So it could have been easily done without IIFE.

Comment: After document.ready, the page is already loaded. So it does not matter if we use it or not. We are just adding more lines of code unneccesary if we are using after document.ready.

Comment: Yes the IIFE is unneeded here, but this does not make your answer correct. The code already works inside a `DOMContentLoaded` callback, and the IIFE being executed only once has nothing to do with the original problem.

Comment: Yes. But you did not observe what is unneeded. So your observation ignored the most important part. So your observation is incorrect as well.

Comment: Is that so? Have you read the bottom part of my answer? But I'll leave it at that. Good day Sir.

Comment: Yes I answered it already. If you have read the first part of my answer. But do not ignore the second part of my answer. Good Day.